# Flutter Getting White Screen Issue

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am new to flutter development. When I try to start flutter app in android studio it syncs but when I run the app go white blank screen. In the command line, I got the error mentioned below.

```
    Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Malformed line in ndk source.properties: "### Android Tool: Source of this archive.".
Malformed line in ndk source.properties: "#Fri Jun 05 17:15:06 IST 2015".
Malformed line in ndk source.properties: "Archive.HostBits=64".
Malformed line in ndk source.properties: "Archive.HostOs=windows".
Malformed line in ndk source.properties: "Pkg.Desc=Android NDK".
Malformed line in ndk source.properties: "Pkg.License=To get started with the Android SDK, you must agree to the following terms and conditions.\n\nThis is the Android SDK License Agreement (the "License Agreement").\n\n1. Introduction\n\n1.1 The Android SDK (referred to in the License Agreement as the "SDK" and specifically including the Android system files, packaged APIs, and SDK library files and tools , if and when they are made available) is licensed to you subject to the terms of the License Agreement. The License Agreement forms a legally binding contract between you and Google in relation to your use of the SDK.\n\n1.2 "Android" means the Android software stack for devices, as made available under the Android Open Source Project, which is located at the following URL\: http\://source.android.com/, as updated from time to time.\n\n1.3 "Google" means Google Inc., a Delaware corporation with principal place of business at 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, United States.\n\n2. Accepting the License Agreement\n\n2.1 In order to use the SDK, you must first agree to the License Agreement. Malformed line in ndk source.properties: "Pkg.LicenseRef=android-sdk-license".
Malformed line in ndk source.properties: "Pkg.Revision=1".
Malformed line in ndk source.properties: "Pkg.SourceUrl=https\://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml".
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
I/Choreographer( 7081): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation( 7081): eglMakeCurrent: 0xad5e4e00: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa2dbf960)
D/EGL_emulation( 7081): eglMakeCurrent: 0xad5e5820: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa5883310)
```

When I use flutter doctor --android-license,

```
   D:\Projects\Flutter_Projects\FlutterUi\flutter_app>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Malformed line in ndk source.properties: "### Android Tool: Source of this archive.".
Malformed line in ndk source.properties: "#Fri Jun 05 17:15:06 IST 2015".
Malformed line in ndk source.properties: "Archive.HostBits=64".
Malformed line in ndk source.properties: "Archive.HostOs=windows".
Malformed line in ndk source.properties: "Pkg.Desc=Android NDK".
Malformed line in ndk source.properties: "Pkg.License=To get started with the Android SDK, you must agree to the following terms and conditions.
All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...
```

When I use flutter doctor -v

```
 [√] Flutter (Channel master, v1.3.14-pre.64, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.379], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.3.14-pre.64 at D:\FlutterMaster\flutter
    • Framework revision 2e637d8303 (51 minutes ago), 2019-03-23 13:20:41 -0400
    • Engine revision 9f878fcb3e
    • Dart version 2.2.1 (build 2.2.1-dev.2.0 None)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\MageshPandian\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 33.4.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.29.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    X Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: What does your flutter doctor command say?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I updated my code.

Comment: @FilledStacks it shows same above error and launch the white screen app

Comment: @CopsOnRoad. That one is default code when we start flutter project. I think have a problem in my android studio flutter setup

Comment: @MageshPandian Please run `flutter doctor` and post your output here.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad posted the result

Comment: @MageshPandian As doctor says, first install the Flutter extension. And then try to run the app. Hope it would work.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I am not using Vscode. I am using Android studio only, it show error in vscode

Comment: @MageshPandian Maybe you can fill an issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md)

Comment: @CopsOnRoad this one totally different

Comment: there is a default splash screen which is rendered by default, refer `AndroidManifest` and `styles.xml` for Android and `LaunchScreen.storyboard` for iOS. If this is not the issue can you add some code? so we can understand more.

Comment: Yes I also got white screen when installing from IPA file :(

Answer (score 0):

Checking the logs you've posted, it's possible that either the emulator is slow based from the frame skip or the code is taking a long time to process. I'm curious if the same behavior occurs running the app using `hot restart` or if the app is run on a physical device.

If you're still having issues, you can file an Issue ticket [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/) along with a minimal repro and steps to replicate the behavior.